# select object data in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want select some data in object as

```
arr: [{number: '1', class: 'a',code: 'aaa111'},
      {number: '2', class: 'b', code: 'bbb222'},
      {number: '3',class: 'c',code: 'ccc333'}
];
```

How to do want just class ???

Comment: you may have a look to [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Please do be precise about what you want. Accessing 'class' properties or modifying the array by deleting unnecessary object properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, though I am assuming that you want something like:

```
    arr:['a','b','c']


    var arr=arr.map(element=>{
        return element.class
    })

    //arr: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```